# Jenkins - publish a list of commits to either email or slack

Tags: jenkins

Need to be able to publish a list of commits included in the latest build.  Would love to do this either via email or slack.  The slack plugin does have an option to "show commit list" but simply can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Take this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin and assuming you are using a standart git plugin for jenkins:

Make a template for email:

```
Commits: 
${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}
```

This will output in:

```
Commits:
Username: stanjer
    - myworkspace/input.h
    - myworkspace/string.h
    - myworkspace/math.h
    -- "Commiting header files"
```

Comment: Cool thanks.  Any ideas on how to also send this info to Slack (or even HockeyApp)

Comment: as mentioned, the "show commit list" simply doesn't do anything that I can see